# How to call functions deployed onto Google Cloud Platform, from an Android application?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

**System Setup:** My application is developed using Android [Android Studio] with Firebase working as a server-less back end. I have used Google Cloud Platform [Node.js] as a server app to deploy Cloud Functions for use with the Firebase Admin SDK.

**Scenario:**
I have an android app that requires two roles within the system (Trainers & Clients). Trainers should be able to create and manage Client accounts within the app.

**Question:** Once my functions have been deployed to the GCP, how can i call them from the application inside my MainActivity.java? How do I take the values from an EditText, send the mapped data to the function, and then split them into their desired fields?

index.ts

```
 export const mkUser = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) =>{
    admin.auth().createUser({
        email: 'user@example.com', //HOW CAN THIS FIELD BE A USER INPUT EMAIL (i unsuccessfully tried 'request.email')
        emailVerified: false,
        password: 'secretPassword', //AND THIS PASSWORD BE A USER INPUT PSWD
        displayName: 'John Doe', //AND THIS A USER INPUT NAME
        photoURL: 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
        disabled: false
      })
        .then(function(userRecord: { uid: any; }) {
          console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
        })
        .catch(function(error: any) {
          console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
        });
  });
```

MainActivity.java

//After reading the Firebase documentation this is the structure they used but is still not clear to me how to the data sent can be processed by the function

```
...
 private Task<String> callCloudFunction() {
        FirebaseFunctions mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("email", "new@example.com");
        data.put("password", "changePassword");
        data.put("displayName", "Mike Example");
        data.put("photoURL", "NULL");

        return mFunctions
                .getHttpsCallable("mkUser")
                .call(data)
                .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) {
                        // ..

                        return (String) task.getResult().getData();
                    }
                });

    }
```

Comment: This is a broad question. You should learn about Firebase SDK for android and follow their documentation to do that, also there are a lot of resources on google. Firebase and GCP share three products: Cloud Firestore, Cloud Functions, and Cloud Storage. These are the same products that exist in the Cloud, simply exposed to client-side developers via Firebase. https://firebase.google.com/firebase-and-gcp. So you can use firebase instead of GCP console and you'll still be using the same product.

Comment: @EraftYps i have removed that side question for clarity as it is not as important. I have followed the Firebase documentation which has helped me get to where i am currently, however after further researching on google most of the information i retrieved helped with calls from web applications rather than Android applications

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable.

Comment: @EraftYps that is the documentation that has lead me to the example above, yet it is still unable to create the account when the call is triggered